# Can a pointer register be used twice?

Tags: assembly, tasm

Hi everyone I'm new to assembly and I am having a hard time to understand why the code below works. What I learnt is si holds a address of the data segment and because a and b sit in different places in the data segment it can't be used for both of them and I would have to use di for b.
But for some reason the code below (which copies the first char of a to the first char of b) works fine

```
.model  small
.stack  100H
.data
  a  db   '     This      is     a          test     $'
  b   db   100 dup('$')
.code
  mov si,0
  mov al,a[si]
  mov b[si],al
.exit
end
```

My main misunderstanding is what is the difference between a[si] to b[si] and to [si]
any explanation would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Note that `si` is zero so it's kinda pointless in this example. You can just do `mov al, a` instead.

Comment: Have you read any of the copious online documentation discussing x86 assembly addressing modes?

Comment: In a high-level language you could do `b[i] = a[i];`, using the same index on both sides. This is *very* similar.

Comment: reading your headline, i'm tempted to write something like "no, DI/SI are single use. Once used, they're wasted and you have to buy a new CPU"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I learnt is si holds a address of the data segment

Traditionally. SI means "source index." However, ever since Protected Mode, the addressing modes have been loosened up a lot, so `si` can be used for a lot more. It's a general-purpose register, after all.

> My main misunderstanding is what is the difference between a[si] to
>   b[si] and to [si] [...]

- `[si]` takes the address in `si` and references the data at that address.
- `a[si]` takes the address in `si` *plus* the address constant `a` to reference data.
- `b[si]` takes the address in `si` *plus* the address constant `b` to reference data.

The line

```
mov al, a[si]
```

moves the byte at `a + si` into `al`.

```
mov b[si], al
```

moves the byte in `al` into the byte at `b + si`. That's a transitive chain of operations and so `a[si] = b[si]` after this.

Comment: Micael: notice how `mov si,0` set's the initial value of `si` to zero, so the first memory value addresses is `a+0`, then written to `b+0`. Then a common pattern of code operating over arrays would do `inc si` to make the `si` value equal to 1, and next `a[si]` (or `[a+si]` in Intel asm syntax) would then operate with address `a+1`.